# Websockets SSL_library_init method crash in ios Simulator

Tags: ios, ssl, libwebsockets

I use CMake to cross compile libwebsockets with ssl support, when I include it on my iOS app. It crashed.

Here is the crash error message:

```
    [1414827913:9557] NOTICE: Initial logging level 7
    [1414827913:9557] NOTICE: Initial logging level 7
    [1414827913:9557] NOTICE: Initial logging level 7
    [1414827913:9557] NOTICE: Library version: 1.3 b47fc59
    [1414827913:9557] NOTICE: Library version: 1.3 b47fc59
    [1414827913:9558] NOTICE: Library version: 1.3 b47fc59
    [1414827913:9558] NOTICE: IPV6 compiled in and enabled
    [1414827913:9558] NOTICE: IPV6 compiled in and enabled
    [1414827913:9558] NOTICE: IPV6 compiled in and enabled
    [1414827913:9558] NOTICE: libev support not compiled in
    [1414827913:9558] NOTICE: libev support not compiled in
    [1414827913:9558] NOTICE: libev support not compiled in
    [1414827913:9559] NOTICE:  static allocation: 4520 + (16 x 256 fds) = 8616 bytes
    [1414827913:9559] NOTICE:  static allocation: 4520 + (16 x 256 fds) = 8616 bytes
    [1414827913:9559] NOTICE:  static allocation: 4520 + (16 x 256 fds) = 8616 bytes
    [1414827913:9560] NOTICE:  canonical_hostname = A03101308205.local
    [1414827913:9560] NOTICE:  canonical_hostname = A03101308205.local
    [1414827913:9560] NOTICE:  canonical_hostname = A03101308205.local
    [1414827913:9560] NOTICE:  per-conn mem: 208 + 1594 headers + protocol rx buf
    [1414827913:9561] NOTICE:  per-conn mem: 208 + 1594 headers + protocol rx buf
    [1414827913:9562] NOTICE:  per-conn mem: 208 + 1594 headers + protocol rx buf
    cpp-tests iOS(84001,0x1194eb000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd491252320: double free
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
    cpp-tests iOS(84001,0x119468000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd491297c70: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
    *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

If I remove the ssl support of libwebcoskets, everything is fine.

My OS is Yosemite 10.10 and iOS SDK is 8.1, xcode version is 6.1, libwebsockets version is 1.3

Comment: Hi Owen, I am facing problem while compiling libwebsocket for iOS. I am getting error system .h file not found. Could you give me step by step procedure to compile for IOS? and I used IOS-cmake file toolchain and sample project.

Comment: @Mahesh You should refer to https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-3rd-party-libs-src for more information.